# How do I create multi-tiered apps?

Tags: android, rest, architecture, cloud

I have a hard time figuring out what should be the architecture design of an app that I want to create or what technology is available for me to create the app.

So the app idea is pretty general: I just want to create some app which people will access on their android or ios device. People can type information into the app which is then made available to other people.

So what I am struggling with is where would I store this information? I know I need to store the information in some database or store it in XML file or Json file. Where would these xml or json files be stored? What services are available to store this data online? How would I connect my android app to access this data through the internet from where ever it's stored?

I need a list of possible options where I could store the data and where I could access the data from my android app. 
Do I need restful API? What is restful API? 
Do I need to store it on an application server? What is an application server anyways?

Comment: How many and which tiers do you have in mind?

Comment: @greenapps Well by multi-tiered I just meant something that will have a lot of clients that access data which is stored on one or more servers. Or stored on databases which are accessed by the servers which then send the data as a response to the client. Basically it seems like a client-server architecture for websites, but I need to build it for phone apps.